# Rails eager loading doesn't work(still n+1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I have included client_person and case_histories but when querying case_histories it still generates n+1 query.
I have tried for a long while but nothing seems to work.

```
@client_records = @records.includes({person: [:client_person, :case_histories]})
```

In person model:

`belongs_to :client_person, class_name: 'Client::Person'
has_many :case_histories, through: :region_profiles, class_name: 'Admin::PeopleCaseHistory'`

the query that generates n+1:

```
@client_records.each do |record|
  record.person.case_histories.select{ |hist| hist.case_type == 2}.first
end
```

Specifically, after correctly loading the case_histories for all clients in the list(resulting from the includes clause), it still one by one queries for the case_histories of each client.

The first query generated by includes:

```
Admin::PeopleCaseHistory Load (46.9ms)  SELECT "case_histories".* FROM "case_histories" WHERE "case_histories"."region_profile_id" IN (411, 16804, 572, 19506, 16539, 692, 4828)
```

The subsequent N+1 queries:

```
Admin::PeopleCaseHistory Load (29.5ms)  SELECT "case_histories".* FROM "case_histories" INNER JOIN "region_profiles" ON "case_histories"."region_profile_id" = "region_profiles"."id" WHERE "region_profiles"."person_id" = $1  [["person_id", 9867]]

Admin::PeopleCaseHistory Load (34.3ms)  SELECT "case_histories".* FROM "case_histories" INNER JOIN "region_profiles" ON "case_histories"."region_profile_id" = "region_profiles"."id" WHERE "region_profiles"."person_id" = $1  [["person_id", 430]]
```

Please advise! 
Thanks

Comment: Try to replace `includes` with `references`

Comment: this doesnt work

Comment: What is the N+1 query you are seeing repeated?

Comment: @Smudge I have added the N+1 query in the post

Comment: updated my answer but still might need more info

Comment: @Smudge oh jeez im sorry it was a typo again, they both should be region_profile_id, i just corrected it. Sorry about the confusion ><. your association graph is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have both `people_region_profile_id` and `region_profile_id` on your `case_histories` table. One of those is getting used during eager-loading, but the other is not.

It would help for you to list out your entire model/relation graph because I'm unable to construct what exactly is going on. It seems to me that your graph looks something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_person
  has_many :region_profiles
  has_many :case_histories, through: :region_profiles
end

class RegionProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :case_histories
end

class CaseHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region_profile
end
```

But clearly I'm missing something if case_histories have two different foreign keys.

Comment: sorry I made a typo in the post. My code indeed was record.person.case_histories.select { |hist| hist.case_type == 2 }.first however this generates the n+1

Comment: Ah, in that case I'd double check your traversals -- make sure that you're not stepping through `region_profiles` inadvertently. And if that doesn't work, I'd load up `rails c` and try that code manually -- watch for queries when you run `client_records.first.person.case_histories.to_a`, etc.